# S3/No buckets showing

Tags: assets, s3

Done this a couple of times before so not sure what's going on, but I'm trying to hook up S3. I have the bucket/group/policy/user all setup. But when I enter Access key ID and Secret access key in Craft and refresh, no buckets show up. No errors, just no bucket. My policy looks like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

If it matters, my bucket resides in London. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and London is relatively new and unsupported at one point, try changing the location to Oregon to see if this works

Answer (score 1):

Tbh I haven't bothered to test it, but this:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::"
},
```

Probably should contain an asterix in the resource, like this:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
},
```